# How to understand this two results?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, chkdsk, bad-sectors

I scan my C Drive using **chkdsk**, it came like this: [image]
chkdsk scan completes in 1 minute. It shows 12 Kb bad sectors.

I scan my C Drive using **MiniTool Partition Wizard**.It came like this:[image]

It shows 9 errors & it took about 17 mins to complete the scan.

It show different results compare to chkdsk.
so which is accurate & what took minitool 17 mins?

Comment: They are both accurate.  It is also possible that since you first did the scan there are more bad sectors.  The more you scan this disk the more error will be discovered, which is typical, with a driver that is starting to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both accurate, but are showing you differant (albeit related) things.

First, note that Chkdsk is only concerned about the filesystem, and doesn't do much of anything with areas of the disk that are unallocated, except scan them for damaged sectors. Your partition tool however, because it is a partitioner, is concerned about disk geometry, so it cares about specific sectors of the disk.

In your case, Check your SMART data. It is likely you have 9 Reallocated Sectors.

As your system encounters bad sectors, it will "mark" (take note of) them, for cleanup later. These are refered to as "Current Pending Sectors". Essentially, at this point it has realized somthing is broken. it hasn't fixed it however.

When chkdsk is run, it will substutite another unused sector for the bad one, by marking the bad sector as offlimits to the filesystem, and translating all calls to the bad sector to addresses for the good one. This is called Sector/block Reallocation, and it "fixes" the problem, such that calls to the bad sector are no longer possible, and the good sector gets called in its place. When this happens, the sector is removed from the SMART "Current Pending Sectors" Count, and added to the Reallocated Sector count.

This is important to understand, because next time you run chkdsk, it will not report the 12KB on damaged sectors (unless they are differant, newly-damaged sectors) because it has already processed them, but the partitioning tool will continue to show the actual bad sectors.

Now, as far as what you are seeing, your filesystem was storing 12KB of data in sectors that are now bad. That may represent all or just some of the bad sectors the partitioner detects. The time differance is caused by chkdsk ignoring sectors that have not been allocated by the filesystem, but the partitioner checks them all. chkdsk doesn't care about bad sectors on which it doesn't already have data, so it doesn't report on those.

Anyway, check your SMART data, and if you notice Reallocated Sector count or Current Pending Sector count rising, it is time to consider replacing the disk. When you have more than a few bad sectors, they tend to grow at an approximately exponential rate, which  can result in massive dataloss as the disk approaches failure.